# Can you batch API requests together for any REST API?

Tags: javascript, vba, rest, api, xmlhttprequest

I am requesting data from an API using Excel VBA several times in a for-loop.
Its pretty slow because every request take some amount of time. So I wanted to batch the request together and get the response back together. So that I can parse the JSON myself in my code which is much more faster.

This is how my API requests look like -

```
Set TestReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
For Count = 1 To 100
    TestReq.Open "GET", "https://api.randomwebsite.com/v1?id=" & Count
    TestReq.Send
    TestReq.responseText  
Next Count
```

Is it possible to batch the API GET requests together somehow? 
Something like -

```
batch=
[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"https://api.randomwebsite.com/v1?id=1"},
[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"https://api.randomwebsite.com/v1?id=2"},
[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"https://api.randomwebsite.com/v1?id=3"},
[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"https://api.randomwebsite.com/v1?id=4"},
....
```

And then get response from API together?

Comment: Are you able to use ES6 features such as the `fetch` (or a similarly promise-based 3rd party library like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) and `Promise` APIs?

Comment: I am using vba for this project, so it doesnt have fetch and promise as far as i know. But if you have a solution using ES6, I can test it with Javascript.

Comment: You could try running the requests asynchronously (though that's a bit more complex to manage...)  Pretty sure you will not be able to send multiple id's in a single request, unless the API supports passing multiple id's.

Comment: Ah, I saw Google and Facebook API having this feature. I thought i will throw my luck in here to see if anyone know how to do it with other APIs lol. You should be right.